# the benefit of using javascript anonymous functions to initiate objects

Tags: javascript

like to ask if the  external parenthises are really necessary?   Like here:

incident.Controller = (...)`     //see code block at the end of this question
I dont think so.   (at least the code works the same for me).

Also, I'd like to ask about the difference between the two snippets of code below.

The benefit writing the code below in a function (the first snippet below) is to scope things to myCompany.incident by using the "use strict" statement.  Like below.  But is this the only difference?
(and i would otherwise write it out as in the snippet beneath it)

```
myCompany.incident = (function(incident) {
  "use strict";
  incident.Contracts = {
    onLoad: function() {
      var controller =
              new myCompany.incident.Controller(Xrm);
      controller.load();
    }
  };

  return incident;
}(myCompany.incident || {}));
```

I would otherwise (if not for "use strict";) write it out like this:

```
   myCompany.incident = myCompany.incident || {};
   myCompany.incident.Contracts = { onLoad: function() {
         var controller = new myCompany.incident.Controller(Xrm);
         controller.load();
       }
     };
```

I dont think "use strict;" is the only difference/consquence of the two snippets, which is the reason for this question.

Thanks, p.

```
    /// <reference path="controller.js"/>
    /*global myCompany: true*/
    myCompany = window.myCompany || {};
    myCompany.incident = (function(incident) {
       "use strict";
        incident.Contracts = {
         onLoad: function() {
          var controller =
            new myCompany.incident.Controller(Xrm);
          controller.load();
        }
      };
      return incident;
    }(myCompany.incident || {}));
```

Comment: Yes, in your case there's really no difference (except for the strict mode).

Comment: don't make the mistake of thinking that in-the-wild JS always has a purpose...